# Echo single image attachment title in wordpress

Tags: php, image, title

I was wondering what is the exact code to be able to get the title on the attachment image page. Here is the code I have right now in my image.php file for the title portion.

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent); ?>" rev="attachment"><?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent); ?> </a><?php echo ' &raquo; $attachment->post-title'; ?></h2>
```

So I want it to show the main post title then the double right arrow and then the single image title but the $attachment->post-title is not the correct command for this.

I am trying this on my test site. Here you can see the exactly what I am referring to. http://pandafeed.net/gave-her-a-bath-and-tucked-her-in-she-passed-out-right-away/thumbnail-for-1407/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should fetch the title for each post's first attached image on the front page (or any post that's part of a list):

```
<?php
  if (! is_singular()) {
    $image_id = get_the_ID();
    // Not necessary, but it's an option:
    //$permalink = get_permalink($image_id);
    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => 1,
      'post_parent' => $image_id
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
      $title = get_the_title($attachments[0]->ID);
      print $title;
    }
  }
?>
```